Graph not rendering in Gremlin Queries on JupyterLab using graph-notebook python package
I am encountering an issue where my Gremlin queries do not render as graphs. I'm unsure if this is related to the Graph Notebook widget, but it does not seem to be functioning as expected in my environment. I am running JupyterLab via JupyterHub, which is deployed on Kubernetes.
Here are the details of my environment:
OS: Linux SMP Debian 5.10.223-1 (2024-08-10) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Browser: Google Chrome
Graph Notebook Version: 4.5.2
Graph Database & Version: JanusGraph 1.0.0
Python Version: 3.9.13

I have attached relevant screenshots at the end for your reference. I would greatly appreciate your guidance on resolving this issue.
Here's the relevant screenshots



The output of the Gremlin query needs to result in a set of path objects from the path() step.  When you're returning just a map of values, there's nothing in the query result that the notebook libraries can use to denote how entities are connected.
